# Pycharm Color of Indent Guides

Tags: pycharm

is there a way to make these lines (Red Arrow) more visible?

I tried different themes to make them more visible but they don't come with darker themes.

[image: SS HERE]

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General

If you can't find it in general, when in Settings > Editor > Color Scheme use search bar at top left to type Guides. They are indent guide, indent guide selected.